# Add a Unity app to new fabric organization, existing firebase project

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine, crashlytics, google-fabric

I have the fabric plugin installed in my Unity project. I set it up and had it tracking an Android install, yesterday. I then deleted the organization in fabric (because I was having trouble linking an existing firebase project that does Auth for this Unity project, to the fabric apps). Now, I can't get fabric to recognize that the SDK is installed and running in builds, under the new organization I created. It's hung on step #1 of the 3: (1 Add the first SDK to your project. Tip: Download and install the Fabric plugin to get started.), and when I try to add an app from the dashboard I'm brought to https://www.fabric.io/kits. But I already have Crashlytics and Answers installed, and this doesn't seem to help me add the app. When, in Unity, I click Prepare Fabric, it's "all done", and takes me back to the onBoard page, rather than the Crashlytics dashboard.

Do I need to start over - revert the project and import the unity package from the latest fabric screen? And it will automatically recognize the install and then the app launch, again?

I feel like I'm being taken in circles here. Restarting is the next thing I'll try. Then I'll be stuck back at the point where I want to find the firebase project we're already using for authentication (but not Crashlytics, yet) and link the app(s) to it.

Thanks.

Comment: Note that Fabric Crashlytics is deprecated, and is only going to work for 6 more months or so. Are you able to try Firebase Crashlytics?

Comment: We are using firebase for authentication. So, the plan had been to use Crashlytics there, but if fabric could help get it running in Unity, that would be nice.

Comment: Ignore my last comment, wasn't aware Firebase Crashlytics wasn't provided for Unity, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I reverted the Unity project code back to before importing the fabric package. I reimported the package and followed the steps in fabric for Unity. Things worked as before and as expected: the Android app appeared after I installed and launched on an Android phone. (needed to delete the FabricSettings.asset for Prepare Fabric to work, again, see [Unity Fabric/Crashytics integration failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50608474/unity-fabric-crashytics-integration-failure))

Second part... It turns out that linking fabric to an existing firebase project is only a visible option for users who are owners of the firebase project - possibly requiring the same email address for their firebase account to be invited to the fabric org.

So now in Firebase > Settings > Integrations, Fabric is there as linked. And the Firebase Quality > Crashlytics tab is showing the one test crash event that I added. Yay.